# Prevent div from stretching its background-image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a div with a background-image defined as follows in my stylesheet:

```css
.information_photo {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://www.ladyblitz.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/carbonara.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="information_photo"></div>
```

As you can see it stretches the original image, instead I want it to just focus on a part of the background-image without stretching or resizing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `100% 100%` `background-size` value means the background should stretch (100%) of the width of the element and (100%) of the height of the element. Have either of them set to `auto`, which will size the undefined dimension automatically, while preserving the images aspect ratio.

You can then choose which portion of the image is visible by adjusting the respective `background-position` style.

```css
.information_photo {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://www.ladyblitz.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/carbonara.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center -30px; /* Visible 30 px from the top */

  /* 100% height, auto width */
  background-size: auto 100%;

  /* 100% width, auto height */
  background-size: 100% auto;
  /* or simply */
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="information_photo"></div>
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks a lot George, I will accept the answer as soon as I can! :)